# How to draw these figures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am writing a paper for a course I'm taking and I would really like to know how to draw these figures in LaTeX.

Thank you

I also need to write information below the figures, so if you could show me how, I would be thankful.

EDIT: There are no rules for the lenghts nor for the angles.
These are finite projective planes.
Like a graph, they do not differ anyhow if we change (in a small amount) lenghts or angles.

Also, the colours of the dots and lines are important. I really do not need the green background tho.

[image: Duality]

Comment: are there any rules for the angles and lengths  -- what is  the purpose of the figure

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: @jsbibra I'll make an edit to the post, sorry

Comment: @Zarko I'm new to LaTeX so I really do not know how to write figures. And these seem like they have a really complex coding for me to find out.

Comment: @hugh_maths `tkz-euclide` package syntax is easy to understand -- below is a simplistic representation of one part of the projection -- a `coordinate` at `0,0` and at `4,0.5` projected at `-60deg` and `255deg` -- `intersection` marked with a red point -- the `color` and `size`  of the point can be varied with the optional parameters within square brackets

Comment: As novice, it will be very helpful to you if you will read documentation for Ti*k*Z package. At leas the first tutorial and then the section *13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths* (Ti*k*Z & PGF manual). Also look for questions here tagged by *intersections*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tricky solution. Place points where you want and draw lines between them with negative `shorten` values. This way, there's no need to find intersections.

```
\documentclass[border=2cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    point/.style={circle, fill=red, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm},
    line/.style 2 args={blue, thick, shorten <=-#2, shorten >=-#1},
    line/.default={1cm}{1cm}]

\node[point] (a){};
\node[point, above right=3cm and 1cm of a] (b){};
\node[point, above left=2.5cm and 1cm of a] (c){};
\node[point, above left=4cm and 3mm of a] (d){};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[line] (a)--(b);
\draw[line={3.5cm}{1cm}] (a)--(c);
\draw[line] (a)--(d);
\draw[line] (b)--(c);
\draw[line={2.5cm}{1cm}] (b)--(d);
\draw[line] (c)--(d);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or another class

\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % no need to load TikZ

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            \tkzDefPoint(0,0){I}
            \tkzDefPoint(4,0.5){J}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[I](-60:5.5){I1}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[J](255:5.5){J1}
            \tkzDrawLine[blue, ultra thick](I,I1)
            \tkzDrawLine[blue, ultra thick](J,J1)
            \tkzInterLL(I,I1)(J,J1)\tkzGetPoint{X}
            \tkzDrawPoint[size=6,fill=red](X)

    \end{tikzpicture}       

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you specify how exactly you think this is easy to understand and in that sense easier than using intersections, such as @Zarko suggested in his comment to the question?

Comment: If you feel an alternative solution is easier feel free to go for it —on this site you will find multiple solutions to one question depending on your uptake choose what you feel is best